# Android studio ActionBar with Tabs inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have created a project with the navigation drawer template and I have different fragments for each navigation item. 
I have an ActionBar with Tabs on one of the fragments and I have set the width to match parent but when I run it the tabs doesn't stick to the actionbar and the width is also not matching the parent. check the code below:

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.yardbird.justice.yardbird.Fragments.DrinksFragment">
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
/>
```

Java:

```
public class DrinksFragment extends Fragment {


public DrinksFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drink, container, false);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Frabment 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Frabment 1"));
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getFragmentManager(),
            tabLayout.getTabCount()));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int numberOfTabs;

    public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int numberOfTabs) {
        super( fragmentManager);
        this.numberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                Tab1Fragment tab1 = new Tab1Fragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2Fragment tab2 = new Tab2Fragment();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return numberOfTabs;
    }
}
```

}

Screen Shot of the app:

[image: screenshot showing when running]

Can anyone help fix that?

Comment: I think you don't need `AppBarLayout ` when you are using it inside fragment. just use `Tablayout` with `viewpager`.

Comment: That didn't work either is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried that and is still not working. the tabs are still in the same place